# Why doesn´t observableArray actualize view after adding items to property in ViewModel?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to build a Treeview like jsTree. Every time a user klicks on item in list, there should be a leaf added that shows all containing files:

[image: Screenshot Treeview]

My ViewModel property self.tree has an array with all folders and subfolders. When I want to add a leaf (clicked Folder), the strucure in my Property self.tree is correct, but the observerbleArray doesn´t seem to react on my manipulation.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
function TreeviewViewModel()
{
    var self = this;

    self.tree = ko.observableArray([
        {
            "data" : "C:/"
        }
    ]);

    self.expandBranch = function (item)
    {
        /* add leaf to clicked item -> observable does not react */

        item['leaf'] = [
                { "data" : "Documents" },
                { "data" : "Photos" },
                { "data" : "Videos" }
        ];
    }  

    console.log(self.tree());
}
```

The `console.log(self.tree());` proves, that my property `self.tree` contains the leaf. But my View doesn´t show it.

my View:

```
<script type="text/html" id="ULTemplate">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <ins class="item-icon" data-bind="click: $root.expandBranch"></ins>
                <a href="#" data-bind="text: data"></a>

                <!-- ko if: $data.hasOwnProperty("leaf") -->
                    <!-- ko template: { name: 'ULTemplate', foreach: leaf } -->
                    <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </li>
        </ul>
    </script>

   <div id="treeview" data-bind="template: { name: 'ULTemplate', foreach: tree }">

   </div>
```

I know, that my View is correct. It tested it with a dummy:

```
dummy = [{
        "data": "C:/",
        "leaf": [
            { "data": "Documents" },
            { "data": "Photos" },
            { "data": "Videos" }
        ]
    }];

    self.tree(dummy);
```

Comment: please provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/G5XJe/

The changes I made to your code

```
<li> 
    <ins class = "item-icon"> </ins>
    <a href="#" data-bind="text: data, click: $root.expandBranch"></a >
    <!-- ko template: { name: 'ULTemplate', foreach: leaf } -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</li>
```

And then this to the JavaScript. I added the leaf property to be there from the start and made it an observable array, this allows for adding more items and allowing it to notify knockout of the changes.

```
var self = this;
self.tree = ko.observableArray([{
    "data": "C:/",
    "leaf": ko.observableArray([])
}]);
self.expandBranch = function (item) {
    /* add leaf to clicked item -> observable does not react */

    item['leaf'].push({
        "data": "Documents",
        "leaf": ko.observableArray([])
    });
    item['leaf'].push({
        "data": "Photos",
        "leaf": ko.observableArray([])
    });
    item['leaf'].push({
        "data": "Videos",
        "leaf": ko.observableArray([])
    });
}
```

Update:

Have a look at this one, i added a property to only allow an item to be clicked once: http://jsfiddle.net/G5XJe/1/

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thanks.